# Passing a DOM element from background.js to content_script.js

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

(I will refer to background.js as **ba.js** and content_script.js as **cs.js**)

**Scenario:**

1. **cs.js** is being injected in every webpage.
2. User might click a context menu button to display a modal on the main webpage.
3. So, this means creating a modal (which has many sub elements and handlers) every time button is clicked.
4. So, I decided to create one element in **ba.js** and then pass it as a message using **chrome.tabs.sendMessage** to **cs.js**

**Problem:**

An empty object (`{}`) is being received in **cs.js**. See logs of **ba.js**:

[image]

But then see log of **cs.js**:

[image]

**Question:**

What's the problem and how can I send a DOM element from **ba.js** to **cs.js**?

#### Relevant Code:

**ba.js**:

```
(function(){
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        type: "normal",
        id: "x",
        title: "Click me!",
    });

    chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab){
        var id = info.menuItemId,
            url = info.pageUrl,
            elm = document.createElement("div");

        elm.classList.add("test");
        elm.appendChild(document.createElement("span"));

        console.log("Element", elm);

        if(id === "x"){     
            msg = {
                task: "doWork",
                elm: elm
            };

            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
                console.log(msg);
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, msg);
            });
        }
    }); 
})();
```

**cs.js**:

```
(function(){
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {          
        if(request.task === "doWork")
            console.log(request.elm);
    });
})();
```

**[Zip file of files to install and check manually](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-MHagh5cA4MQUh1SGtwOElpNnM/view?usp=sharing)**

I have included all relevant info. If you may feel something is missing, please tell me. Please include well researched answers. Thanks!

Comment: It's only possible to send JSON-serializable objects via sendMessage ([doc link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)). Also there's no need for [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) in background and content scripts because they all run in "isolated worlds". BTW I think html5 template element might be useful to avoid duplication of DOM construction.

Comment: Tried finding a duplicate but failed which is weird as I was pretty sure this question is asked regularly...

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for your answer and feedback. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: I don't know a canonical dupe, but will use one I answered